# Multithreading in AWS boto pagination Python not working

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-multithreading, boto, botocore

I tried multithreading with paginator but instead of running on multiple thread, it is running on a single thread.

- response: <class 'botocore.paginate.PageIterator'>
- page.get('Contents') return a list of dict containing object name and object size
- Since "list_objects_v2" only list 1000 object per response So that’s why we need Paginator to iterate over every page where each page should have 1000 object.

I was giving the response iterator to the thread so that this iterator load can be distributed between different threads. But instead of that whole iterator works on single thread

```
def list_s3_files_using_paginator_multithreading(bucket_name, prefix = None):
    import boto3
    from threading import Thread
    from queue import Queue   
    """
    This functions list all files in s3 using paginator.
    Paginator is useful when you have 1000s of files in S3.
    S3 list_objects_v2 can list at max 1000 files in one go.
    :return: None
    """
    def safe_dedicated_writing_thread(filepath, queue):
        with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
            while True:
                # Retrieve s3 ls object name from the queue
                line = queue.get()
                
                # check if we have reached end of s3 ls dump
                # then we close the file
                if line is None:
                    break
                
                # Write to file
                f.write(line)
                
                # In Python, files are automatically flushed
                # while closing them but, a programmer can flush
                # a file before closing it
                f.flush()
                
                # Mark the unit of work complete
                queue.task_done()
                
            # mark the exit signal as processed, after the file was closed
            queue.task_done()
            
    # Create a shared queue
    queue = Queue()
    
    # Path of the shared file
    filepath = 's3_ls_dump.txt'
    
    # Create And Start the file writer Thread
    writer_thread = Thread(target = safe_dedicated_writing_thread, args = (filepath, queue), daemon = True)
    writer_thread.start()
    
    
    # Creating a Paginator to list 1000 object per response
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    response = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix = prefix,  PaginationConfig={"PageSize": 1000})
 
        
    def list_object(page):
        files = page.get('Contents')
        for file in files:
            queue.put(file['Key'])
    
    # Configure worker Thread
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(list_object, response)
    
    
    # Signal the file writer thread that we are done
    queue.put(None)
    
    # Wait for all the queue to be processed
    queue.join()
```

I also tried one more way to mutlithread AWS boto pagination. Is it even possible to multithread?

```
def list_object(page, queue):
    files = page.get('Contents')
    for file in files:
        queue.put(file['Key'])


threads = [Thread(target = list_object, args = (page, queue)) for page in response]


for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
    

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: You can't get multiple pages from the paginator at once.  Each call to get a page needs the "ContinuationToken" from to the previous page, so it's necessarily single threaded logically.  At best, you can process the results from a given page in a background thread, but unless your processing is surprisingly bad, the network time will dwarf this.  If you need a faster way to enumerate a large bucket, look into [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html)